# Anonymous types in LINQ

Tags: linq, anonymous-types

I am using the following code to get a record from my database table `tblDatabases`. I then populate Controls on a Form based on the value.  I have used some functions to get the values needed for displaying in a text box (e.g. the display value is different than the value.

The `DetailData` is an object in my base form class. Initially I just got the record from the table as is and I was able to cast the `DetailData` to the `tblDatabases` and use reflection to get all of the values for the data and populate the controls on my form.

I am no longer able to cast the `DetailData` to my table because of the anonymous types.

I would like to be able to use reflection on the `DetailData` to get the values.

Thanks,
Brad

```
  DetailData = (from db in priorityDataContext.tblDatabases
      where db.DatabaseID == Id
      select new
        {
            db.DatabaseID,
            db.DatabaseName,
            db.Purpose,
            db.BackEnd,
            db.FrontEnd,
            db.Version,
            db.ProducesReports,
            db.MultiUser,
            db.UserDescription,
            Developer = priorityDataContext.func_get_employee_name(db.Developer),
            DeptOwner = priorityDataContext.func_get_dept_name(db.DeptOwner),
            db.Source_Code_Path,
            db.Notes,
            db.Active,
            db.row_entry_time_stamp,
            row_oper_name = priorityDataContext.func_get_employee_name(db.Developer),
            db.row_last_chng_time_stamp,
            row_last_chng_oper_name = priorityDataContext.func_get_employee_name(db.Developer)
        }).SingleOrDefault();


protected virtual void PopulateDetailControlsA(List<Control> controlContainers, string srcDataTableName)
{
    switch (srcDataTableName)
    {
        case "tblDatabase" :
            break;
    }

    var database = (tblDatabase) DetailData;
    var type = typeof(tblDatabase);
    var properties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

    foreach (var controlContainer in controlContainers)
    {
        foreach (var propertyInfo in properties)
        {
            if (!ControlExists(controlContainer, propertyInfo.Name)) continue;

            var txtExtControl = controlContainer.Controls[propertyInfo.Name] as ExtendedTextBox;
            if (txtExtControl != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(database, null).ToString();

                    txtExtControl.Text = value;
                }
                catch (NullReferenceException)
                {
                }
                continue;
            }

            var lnklblControl = controlContainer.Controls[propertyInfo.Name] as ExtendedLinkLabel;
            if (lnklblControl != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(database, null).ToString();

                    lnklblControl.Text = value;
                }
                catch (NullReferenceException)
                {
                }
                continue;
            }

            var chkControl = controlContainer.Controls[propertyInfo.Name] as ExtendedCheckBox;
            if (chkControl != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(database, null).ToString();

                    switch (value)
                    {
                        case "True":
                            chkControl.CheckState = CheckState.Checked;
                            break;
                        case "False":
                            chkControl.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked;
                            break;
                    }
                }
                catch (NullReferenceException)
                {
                    chkControl.CheckState = CheckState.Indeterminate;
                }
                continue;
            }

            var cmbControl = controlContainer.Controls[propertyInfo.Name] as ExtendedComboBox;
            if (cmbControl != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(database, null).ToString();

                    cmbControl.ValueMember = value;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It might help if you could post the minimal amount of code necessary to reproduce your problem.  Right now, it's kind of tough to figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

What technology are you using for your UI? If you could use binding you would not need to worry about reflection on the anonymous type and then could also use converters if you need to format/calculate values from this.

From your response can't you just use the connection to the linq and then bind this to the combo box?

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var item = new DataClassesDataContext();
        var stuff = item.Entity.Where(c => c.Property.Contains("something"));
        comboBox1.DataSource = stuff;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "PIN";
    }
```

Comment: It is an existing Winforms Application.  I was trying to switch out the sql commands and use linq.  We display things like an operators name based on a user pin.  So currently the sql statement includes a function that get's the user name from the Pin.  In this manner the combo box value member is the user pin and the display value is the user's name.